# How to split a string using an integer array?

Tags: parsing, ada

I am trying to split a string using an integer array as mask.
The task is simple but I am not accustomed to ADA (which is a constraint).

Here is my code. It works exept that I have an one character offset when testing against a file. Can someone help me remove this offset. it is drinving me nuts.

generic_functions.adb :

```
package body Generic_Functions is

   -- | Sums up the elements of an array of Integers
   function Sum_Arr_Int(Arr_To_Sum: Int_Array) return Integer is
      Sum: Integer;
   begin
      Sum := 0;
      for I in Arr_To_Sum'Range loop
     Sum := Sum + Arr_To_Sum(I);
      end loop;
      return Sum;
   end Sum_Arr_Int;

   -- | Split up a String into a array of Unbounded_String following pattern from an Int_Array
   function Take_Enregistrements(Decoup_Tab: Int_Array; Str_To_Read: String) return Str_Array is
      Previous, Next : Integer;
      Arr_To_Return  : Str_Array(Decoup_Tab'Range);
   begin
      if Sum_Arr_Int(Decoup_Tab) > Str_To_Read'Length then
     raise Constraint_Error;
      else
     Previous := Decoup_Tab'First;
     Next     := Decoup_Tab(Decoup_Tab'First);
     for I in Decoup_Tab'Range loop
        if I /= Decoup_Tab'First then
           Previous          := Next + 1;
           Next              := (Previous - 1) + Decoup_Tab(I);
        end if;
        Arr_To_Return(I)  := To_Unbounded_String(Str_To_Read(Previous..Next));
     end loop;
     return Arr_To_Return;
      end if;
   end Take_Enregistrements;

end Generic_Functions;
```

generic_functions.ads :

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

package Generic_Functions is

   -- | Types
   type Int_Array is array(Positive range <>) of Integer;
   type Str_Array is array(Positive range <>) of Unbounded_String;
   -- | end of Types

   -- | Functions
   function Sum_Arr_Int(Arr_To_Sum: Int_Array) return Integer;
   function Take_Enregistrements(Decoup_Tab: Int_Array; Str_To_Read: String) return Str_Array;
   -- | end of Functions

end Generic_Functions;
```

generic_functions_tests.adb :

```
with Ada.Text_IO;           use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

with Generic_Functions;     use Generic_Functions;

procedure Generic_Functions_Tests is

   -- | Variables
   Decoup_Test   : constant Int_Array(1..8) := (11, 19, 60, 24, 255, 10, 50, 255);
   Test_Str_Arr  : Str_Array(Decoup_Test'Range);
   Test_Str_Arr2 : Str_Array(Decoup_Test'Range);
   Test_Str_Arr3 : Str_Array(Decoup_Test'Range);
   --Test_Int      : Integer;
   Test_Handle   : File_Type;
   -- | end of Variables

begin

   Open(Test_Handle, In_File, "EXPORTFINAL.DAT");
   Test_Str_Arr  := Take_Enregistrements(Decoup_Test, Get_Line(Test_Handle));
   Test_Str_Arr2 := Take_Enregistrements(Decoup_Test, Get_Line(Test_Handle));
   Test_Str_Arr3 := Take_Enregistrements(Decoup_Test, Get_Line(Test_Handle));

   for I in Test_Str_Arr'Range loop
      Put_Line(To_String(Test_Str_Arr(I)));
   end loop;

   for I in Test_Str_Arr2'Range loop
      Put_Line(To_String(Test_Str_Arr2(I)));
   end loop;

   for I in Test_Str_Arr3'Range loop
      Put_Line(To_String(Test_Str_Arr3(I)));
   end loop;

   --  for I in Test_Str_Arr'Range loop
   --     Test_Int := To_String(Test_Str_Arr(I))'Length;
   --     Put_Line(Integer'Image(Test_Int));
   --  end loop;


   --  for I in Test_Str_Arr2'Range loop
   --     Test_Int := To_String(Test_Str_Arr2(I))'Length;
   --     Put_Line(Integer'Image(Test_Int));
   --  end loop;

   --  for I in Test_Str_Arr3'Range loop
   --     Test_Int := To_String(Test_Str_Arr3(I))'Length;
   --     Put_Line(Integer'Image(Test_Int));
   --  end loop;

   Close(Test_Handle);

end Generic_Functions_Tests;
```

and finaly the file:

```
000000000012012-01-01 10:00:00                                                         IBM                     IBM                                                                                                                                                                                                                     COMPAGNIE IBM FRANCE 17 AVENUE DE l'EUROPE     92275                               BOIS-COLOMBES CEDEX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 CONFIGURATION COMPLETE SERVEUR000000000000000000000019    .6000000000001000000000000000000001000.00000000000000000000000000000196.00000000000000000000000000001196.00000000
000000000022012-01-01 11:00:00                                                   MICROSOFT                     MSC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 39 QUAI DU PRESIDENT ROOSEVELT     92130                               ISSY-LES-MOULINEAUX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 AMENAGEMENT SALLE INFORMATIQUE000000000000000000000019.6000000000001000000000000000000001000.00000000000000000000000000000196.00000000000000000000000000001196.00000000
000000000032012-01-01 12:00:00                                                   MICROSOFT                     MSC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 39 QUAI DU PRESIDENT ROOSEVELT     92130                               ISSY-LES-MOULINEAUX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 TESTS SUR SITE000000000000000000000019.6000000000001000000000000000000003226.52000000000000000000000000000632.39792000000000000000000000003858.91792000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     DELEGATION TECHNICIEN HARD000000000000000000000019.60000000000000000000000000000001.00000000000000000000000000001000.00000000000000000000000000000196.00000000000000000000000000001196.00000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
if I = Decoup_Tab'Last then
   Arr_To_Return(I)     := To_Unbounded_String(Str_To_Read(Previous..Next));
end if;
```

will overwrite the last element in your array.

Also, are you sure that the line number (00000000001, 00000000002, etc) is one of the strings you want to split based on the integer mask? As your code is right now, you use '11' twice, once for the line number and once for the date-field. If you skip the line number, the other numbers seem to make more sense.

Comment: Your pointers were good. I updated with working code. The mask was wrong as I was splitting up the date. And also the loop was messed up. Thanks.